# Qstat not showing correct memory or cpu usage for MPI job

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

If I run `qstat -ext` or `qstat -j [JOBID]` for my MPI job, qstat reports a cpu usage of 1 second, and memory usage in the hundreds of megabytes. I know that neither of these values is correct. The job is consuming gigabytes of memory, and has been running for days. Neither is being reflected in the output of qstat.

How can I get an accurate estimate of the memory consumed by my job as it is running? Do I have an incorrect setting that is causing my qstat output to incorrectly gather resource usage from the hosts?